# navigation in multiple inputs when reaching max length

Tags: javascript, forms, input

I am basically trying to have these three text inputs representing 00h 00m 00s for my timer to get user input. I wanted to be able to make google timer (the one you can see if you just type timer in google) but I got stuck with getting navigation right - when user put two digits then focus into next input and when there is no "form" element break out of the loop. However, I keeping getting "Cannot read property 'firstElementChild' of null".

Also, what I hope to see is when user type the number (ex. 01 : 30: 00) and then hit enter I want to be able to get the user value so then I can work on building timer based on the user input however, the keypress event for listening "Enter" key to fire a submit doesn't seem to work and e.preventDefault() doesn't work either..

```
<div class="form-container">
   <form class="1" action=""> 
        <input class="1" type="text" maxlength="2" placeholder="00:">
   </form>
   <form class="2" action=""> 
        <input class="2" type="text" maxlength="2" placeholder="00:">
    </form>
    <form class="3" action=""> 
        <input class="3" type="text" maxlength="2" placeholder="00:">           
    </form>
</div>



formContainer.addEventListener('keyup', function(e){
    let target = e.srcElement || e.target;
    let targetValue = target.attributes["maxlength"].value
    let maxLength = parseInt(targetValue, 10);
    let currentLength = target.value.length;

    if(currentLength >= maxLength) {
      let next = target;
      let nextInputParent = target.parentElement.nextElementSibling
      let nextInputInNextSibling = nextInputParent.firstElementChild

      while (next = nextInputInNextSibling){
        if (next.parentElement == null){
          break;
        }

        if (next.tagName.toLowerCase() === "input") {
            next.focus();
            break;
          }
      }
   }
    // Move to previous field if empty (user pressed backspace)
    else if (currentLength === 0) {
      let previous = target;
      let previousInputInPreviousSibling = target.parentElement.previousElementSibling.children[0]
      while (previous = previousInputInPreviousSibling) {
          if (previous == null)
              break;
          if (previous.tagName.toLowerCase() === "input") {
              previous.focus();
              break;
          }
      }
  }
})

form.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
  if(e.key == "Enter" || e.keyCode == 13){
    console.log("submit");
      e.preventDefault()
      form.submit()
      let userInput = inputEl.value
      let countdown = 60 * userInput

      timer = new Timer(countdown, userInput)
      timer.start()
      toggleStartTimer.textContent = "stop"
      timer.isOn = true
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why using three separate forms for each `input` element? You can use one form, with an `oninput` event handler for each `input` element. Basically, an `oninput` event fires whenever the user presses a key/writes anything inside the `input`.

Then, you can use the form's `onsubmit` handler to handle hitting Enter, like so:

```js
//event handler that will fire whenever the user types something in one of the inputs
$("#timer input[type='text']").on("input", function() {
  //inside the event handler, `this` refers to the input element that fired the event 
  if(this.value.length == 2) {
  
    //move to the next input, if any
    if(next = $(this).next("#timer input[type='text']")[0]) {
      $(this).blur(); //lose focus from the element
      next.focus();
    }
  }
});

//handling case when user presses 'Enter' 
//(note that using this approach, one of the inputs should be in focus when Enter is hit)
$("#timer").on("submit", function(e) {
  //here e is your event object
  e.preventDefault();
  //build your timer and start it
  console.log("Timer started!");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-container">
   <form id="timer" action=""> 
        <input class="1" type="text" maxlength="2" placeholder="00:">
        <input class="2" type="text" maxlength="2" placeholder="00:">
        <input class="3" type="text" maxlength="2" placeholder="00:"> 
        <!-- An input type='submit' is needed, otherwise the form will never submit when Enter is hit.-->
        <input type='submit' value='submit' style='display:none'/>
    </form>
</div>
```

Or, using plain Javascript:

```js
//event handler that will fire whenever the user types something in one of the inputs

var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('#timer input[type="text"]');
for(let input of inputs) {
  input.oninput = function() {
    if(this.value.length == 2) {
      //move to the next input, if any
      next = this.nextElementSibling;
      if(next && next.type == 'text') {
        this.blur(); //lose focus from the element
        next.focus();
      }
    }
  }
}

//handling case when user presses 'Enter' 
//(note that using this approach, one of the inputs should be in focus when Enter is hit)
$("#timer").on("submit", function(e) {
  //here e is your event object
  e.preventDefault();
  //build your timer and start it
  console.log("Timer started!");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-container">
   <form id="timer" action=""> 
        <input class="1" type="text" maxlength="2" placeholder="00:">
        <input class="2" type="text" maxlength="2" placeholder="00:">
        <input class="3" type="text" maxlength="2" placeholder="00:"> 
        <!-- An input type='submit' is needed, otherwise the form will never submit when Enter is hit.-->
        <input type='submit' value='submit' style='display:none'/>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey! thanks for the help but any chance you could do this with vanila javascript ?

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked perfectly. Could you explain a bit though why the last input with type="submit" is needed  to fire a submission? didn't know about that bit at all!

Answer (score 0):

I think the better way is rely on some max constrains, not the input length. I've created a simple snippet for you. There are 3 inputs and a timer which starts when you hit "Enter".

```js
const form = document.querySelector(".timer");
const time = document.querySelector(".time");

const limits = {
  hours: 23,
  minutes: 59,
  seconds: 59
};

const multipliers = {
  hours: val => (parseInt(val, 10) || 0) * 60 * 60,
  minutes: val => (parseInt(val, 10) || 0) * 60,
  seconds: val => parseInt(val, 10) || 0
};

let interval = null;
let totalTime = 0;

form.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    totalTime = Array.from(form.querySelectorAll("input")).reduce(function(
      sum,
      input
    ) {
      const { name, value } = input;
      return (sum += multipliers[name](value));
    },
    0);

    if (totalTime > 0) {
      if (interval) {
        clearInterval(interval);
      }

      interval = setInterval(() => {
        totalTime--;
        time.innerHTML = totalTime;
      }, 1000);
    }
  }

  const { name, value } = event.target;

  const parsedValue = parseInt(value, 10);
  const newValue = Math.min(limits[name], parsedValue);

  if (parsedValue > newValue) {
    const sibling = event.target.nextElementSibling;
    if (sibling && "focus" in sibling) {
      sibling.focus();
    }

    event.target.value = newValue;
  }
});
```

```html
 <form class="timer">
  <input name="hours" placeholder="00"/>
  <input name="minutes" placeholder="00"/>
  <input name="seconds" placeholder="00"/>
 </form>

 <h1 class="time"></h1>
```

Comment: And by the way, this is vanilla js =)